# salesforce changes parent id of email Attachment to Case Id eventhough I set it to EmailMessage's Id

Tags: attachment, case, singleemailmessage

I am trying to create an Attachment with ParentId as the EmailMessage's Id but  salesforce somehow changes it to the Case Id.
I need the ParentId to be EmailMessage Id as I want to select attachments for individual EmailMessages.

java code

```
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage();
    email.setParentId(caseId);
    email.setTextBody(emailBody);
    email.setFromAddress(email);
    String emailId = sfAgent.createSobject(email);
    if(emailId != null && emailId.length() > 0)
    {
        getMessages().add(new SimpleMessage("Reply posted."));
        if(attachment != null)
        {
            Attachment sfAttachment = new Attachment();
            sfAttachment.setParentId(emailId);
            sfAttachment.setName(attachment.getFileName());
            sfAttachment.setContentType(attachment.getContentType());
            byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
            try
            {
                bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(attachment.getInputStream());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sfAttachment.setBody(bytes);
            if(sfAgent.createSobject(sfAttachment) == null)
            {
                getErrors().addGlobalError(new LocalizableError("reply.attachment.failed"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code ;) "Works for me" - in my current employee's organisation I've written an inbound email handler where I first save `EmailMessage`, then the attachments and it just works (I was actually asked to provide a flag "case has attachments" because they don't look at rel. list unless they have to)... Maybe you have some triggers at play (on Case or Task I imagine, I don't think we can write triggers on `EmailMessage`).

Comment: added my java code to the question. I checked `case`, `task` and there is no trigger on it.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't say it's Java :D I thought it's something like [inbound email handler](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_inbound_using.htm) but it looks like you're just saving the raw objects from Java app... I understand the "Email to Case" is enabled? The insert of `EmailMessage` is successful and Id starts with "02s"? Can you use debug log? While making this request? I wonder if you have triggers on `EmailMessage` or `Attachment`...

Comment: I tested "Email to Case" with attachments and `Attachment` got `Case` Id as the ParentId.
I tried debugging many times and everything works fine except when I select `Attachement` the parent id is set to `Case` id. No triggesrs on `EmailMessage` or `Attachment` either.